# How to overwrite the function \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView::getContentRecordsPerColumn

Tags: typo3

I would like to change the function `\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView::getContentRecordsPerColumn` a little bit. But I don't like to overwrite the whole class. There is no hook and no signal in the nearby programming code.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

> You could write an XClass that extends
>   ﻿⁠⁠⁠⁠`\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView﻿⁠⁠⁠⁠` and just override
>   the method ﻿⁠⁠⁠⁠`getContentRecordsPerColumn()`

Answer from [Andreas Fernandez](https://typo3.slack.com/team/a.fernandez) on typo3.slack.com